# UiSearchBar to UiCollectionView in Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uisearchbar, uitabbar

I have 2 tabs at the top of the screen. Every page contains collectionView. And I have to create a searchBar at the top of collectionView. I want it to look like in Settings App (appear when scrolling down and disappear when scrolling up).
Here the code that I use for the search component. But as I don't have navigationBar inside the page it doe's not show.

Please help me to have a search between tabBar and collectionView.

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    var filtered:[String] = []
    var searchActive : Bool = false
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var items = ["Apple", "Orange", "Apple", "Orange", "Apple", "Orange", "Apple", "Orange", "Apple", "Orange", "Apple", "Orange"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self

        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.searchController.delegate = self
        self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search..."
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar

        self.definesPresentationContext = true
        self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for Items"

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            if searchActive {
                return filtered.count
            }
            else
            {
                return items.count
            }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0
        cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0

        return cell
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController)
    {
        let searchString = searchController.searchBar.text

        filtered = items.filter({ (item) -> Bool in
            let countryText: NSString = item as NSString

            return (countryText.range(of: searchString!, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive).location) != NSNotFound
        })

        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = true
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarBookmarkButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        if !searchActive {
            searchActive = true
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }

        searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also faced the same problem and creating UISerchBar instead of UISearchController is the best way to accomplish your goal.

here is the example of setting UISearchBar to be exactly as functional as UISearchBarController:

**setting SearchBar**

```
let searchBar: UISearchBar = {
       
        let searchBar = UISearchBar()
        searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(1.0)
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search for exercise"
        searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clear
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        searchBar.returnKeyType = .search
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        searchBar.showsBookmarkButton = false
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        
        return searchBar
    }()
```

**Setting its delegate and also do not forget to set definesPresentationContext to false because otherwise searchBar wont appear**

searchBar.delegate = self
self.definesPresentationContext = false

**custom functions for searchBar**
**Here we are setting behavior of SearchBar**

```
extension YourViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = true
        self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.searchBar.text = ""
        self.filtered = []
        searchActive = false
        self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        
        if searchBar.text! == " "  {
            filtered = exercises
            collectionView.reloadData()
        } else {
        
        filtered = exercises.filter({ (item) -> Bool in
            
            return (item.exerciseNameLabel?.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(String(searchBar.text!)))!
            
            })
        
        collectionView.reloadData()
        }
        
    }
    
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    
}
```

I hope it will help you with your issue:)